# Optimization of foldLeft

Tags: scala

I'm using the following code, and I'm looking for some ideas to make some optimizations.

*analyzePayload:*

**Input:** payload which is `JsObject` and list of rules, each rule has several conditions.

**Output:** `MyReport` of all the rules which succeed, notApplicable or failed on this specific payload.

The size of the list can be pretty big, also each Rule has a big amount of conditions.

I am looking for some ideas on how to optimize that code, maybe with a lazy collection? view? stream? tailrec? and why - Thanks!

Also, note that I have `anaylzeMode` which can run only until one rule succeeds for ex.

```
def analyzePayload(payload: JsObject, rules: List[Rule]): MyReport = {
    val analyzeMode = appConfig.analyzeMode
    val (succeed, notApplicable, failed) = rules.foldLeft((List[Rule](), List[Rule](), List[Rule]())) { case ( seed @ (succeedRules,notApplicableRules,failedRules), currRule) =>

      // Evaluate Single Rule
      def step(): (List[Rule], List[Rule], List[Rule]) = evalService.eval(currRule, payload) match {

        // If the result is succeed
        case EvalResult(true, _, _) => (currRule :: succeedRules, notApplicableRules, failedRules)

        // If the result is notApplicable 
        case EvalResult(_, missing @ _ :: _, _) => (succeedRules, currRule :: notApplicableRules, failedRules
        )

        // If the result is unmatched
        case EvalResult(_, _, unmatched @ _ :: _) => (succeedRules, notApplicableRules, currRule :: failedRules)
      }

      analyzeMode match {
        case UNTIL_FIRST_SUCCEED => if(succeedRules.isEmpty) step() else seed
        case UNTIL_FIRST_NOT_APPLICABLE => if(notApplicableRules.isEmpty) step() else seed
        case UNTIL_FIRST_FAILED => if(failedRules.isEmpty) step() else seed
        case DEFAULT => step()
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unknown mode = ${analyzeMode}")
      }
    }

    MyReport(succeed.reverse, notApplicable.reverse, failed.reverse)
  }
```

---

**First Edit:**
Changed the code to use `tailrec` from @Tim Advise, any other suggestions? or some suggestions to make the code a little prettier?
Also, i wanted to ask if there any difference to use `view` before the foldLeft on the previous implementation.
Also maybe use other collection such as `ListBuffer` or `Vector`

```
  def analyzePayload(payload: JsObject, actionRules: List[ActionRule]): MyReport = {
    val analyzeMode = appConfig.analyzeMode

    def isCompleted(succeed: List[Rule], notApplicable: List[Rule], failed: List[Rule]) = ((succeed, notApplicable, failed), analyzeMode) match {
      case (( _ :: _, _, _), UNTIL_FIRST_SUCCEED) | (( _,_ :: _, _), UNTIL_FIRST_NOT_APPLICABLE) | (( _, _, _ :: _), UNTIL_FIRST_FAILED) => true
      case (_, DEFAULT) => false
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unknown mode on analyzePayload with mode = ${analyzeMode}")
    }

    @tailrec
    def _analyzePayload(actionRules: List[ActionRule])(succeed: List[Rule], notApplicable: List[Rule], failed: List[Rule]): (List[Rule], List[Rule] ,List[Rule]) = actionRules match {
      case Nil | _ if isCompleted(succeed, notApplicable, failed) => (succeed, notApplicable, failed)
      case actionRule :: tail => actionRuleService.eval(actionRule, payload) match {
        // If the result is succeed
        case EvalResult(true, _, _) => _analyzePayload(tail)(actionRule :: succeed, notApplicable, failed)

        // If the result is notApplicable
        case EvalResult(_, missing @ _ :: _, _) => _analyzePayload(tail)(succeed, actionRule :: notApplicable, failed)

        // If the result is unmatched
        case EvalResult(_, _, unmatched @ _ :: _) => _analyzePayload(tail)(succeed, notApplicable, actionRule :: failed)
      }
    }

    val res = _analyzePayload(actionRules)(Nil,Nil,Nil)
    MyReport(res._1, res._2, res._3)
  }
```

---

**Edit 2: (Questions)**

1. If there result will be forwarded to the Client - There no meaning for do it as `view`? since all the data will be evaluated right?
2. Maybe should I use `ParSeq` instead? or this will be just slower since the operation of the `evalService.eval(...)` is not a heavy operation?

Comment: Can you please add the definitions of `Rule` and `MyReport`?

Comment: @TomerShetah `Rule` case class which contains `List[Conditions]`, each Condition can run on a `JsValue` payload and output, if all `conitions` succeed the rule will be marked as `succeed`, if 1 conditions at least cannot run on the payload, its will marked as `notApplicable` and if at least one failed, its will marked as `failed`.
Regarding `MyReport` - case class that contains all the Rules that succeed, notApplicable and fals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two obvious optimisations:

Use a tail-recursive function rater than `foldLeft` so that the compiler can generate an optimised loop and terminate as soon as the appropriate rule is found.

Since `analyzeMode` is constant, take the `match` outside the `foldLeft`. Either have separate code paths for each mode, or use `analyzeMode` to select a function that is used inside the loop to check for termination.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim, I have several questions:

1. How `tailrec` perform optimization over `foldLeft`?

2. How can I take out the `match` from the foldLeft? Since i need to know if at least one rule is `succeed/failed/notApplicable` to know if continue with the evaluation.

Comment: Scala converts tail-recursive calls to a jump back to the start of the function, creating a loop than can then be optimised further using standard techniques. `foldLeft` is a pre-compiled and therefore cannot be further optimised at compile time. Also, using a recursive call allows the operation to stop as soon as it has an answer.

Comment: You could have a method `isComplete(List[Rule], List[Rule], List[Rule])` that returns `true` when the operation is complete, otherwise `false`. The code would continue until this returned false. There would be a different `isComplete` implementation for each termination condition, and the correct one would be chosen before entering the loop. Then the test is just a function call rather than a multi-way `match`. It would be even more efficient to a custom version for each termination condition but that would probably be too much code

Comment: I edited the question with your advice, thanks @Tim
Any other suggestions?  Also i added a question regarding the `view` option with I not so much familiar with..

Answer (score -2):

The code is rather fine, the main thing to revisit would be to make `evalService.eval` evaluate multiple rules in a single traversal of the json object, assuming the size of the json is not negligible

Comment: Each rule need to be isolated from other rules since each rule has his own conditions which are checked on each Payload, there no logical intersection between the Rules..